# How to open partial view modal when datatables row click?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have general modal structure which is located on my layout.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="m_modal_general">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div id="generalModal" class="modal-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my customer index page i can easly call modal content as partial view from controller.

```
$(function () {
    $("#newCustomer").click(function () {
        var $buttonClicked = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Customer/Customer_Add",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#generalModal').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });
    });
});


public IActionResult Customer_Add()
{
   return PartialView("~/Views/Customer/AddCustomerPartial.cshtml");
}
```

Now i want to get another partial when i clicked datatables row but ajax call result give error. What's the wrong in my code ?

```
function OperationDetail() {
    var table = $('#tbloperations').DataTable();
    $('#tbloperations tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {        
        var data = table.row(this).data();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Customer/CustomerOperationDetail_Read',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { customerOperationId: data.Id },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#generalModal').html(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });
    });
}

public async Task<ActionResult> CustomerOperationDetail_Read(int customerOperationId){

var result = await operationsBusiness.GetCustomerOperationDetails(new GetCustomerOperationDetailsCommand {

                OperationId = customerOperationId
            });
 CustomerOperationDetailsVm vm = new CustomerOperationDetailsVm();

 vm.CustomerOperationDetails = result.Result;

return PartialView("~/Views/Customer/OperationDetailsPartial.cshtml",vm);            
}
```

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i changed datatype json to html. It worked.

```
function OperationDetail(customerOperationId) {
        if (customerOperationId > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Customer/CustomerOperationDetail_Read',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { customerOperationId: customerOperationId },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#generalModal').html(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in this function . 
try this solution :

```
  function OperationDetail() {
        var table = $('#tbloperations').DataTable();
        $('#tbloperations tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {        
            var data = table.row(this).data();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Customer/CustomerOperationDetail_Read',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { customerOperationId: data.Id },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#generalModal').html(result);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE** 
try Try to put this code :

```
$(function () {
    $("#newCustomer").click(function () {
        var $buttonClicked = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Customer/Customer_Add",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#generalModal').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });
    });
});


public IActionResult Customer_Add()
{
   return PartialView("~/Views/Customer/AddCustomerPartial.cshtml");
}
```

the other function :

```
  function OperationDetail() {
        var table = $('#tbloperations').DataTable();
        $('#tbloperations tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {        
            var data = table.row(this).data();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Customer/CustomerOperationDetail_Read',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { customerOperationId : data.Id },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#generalModal').html(result);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
                }
            });
        });
    }




      public async Task<ActionResult> CustomerOperationDetail_Read(int customerOperationId){

        var result = await operationsBusiness.GetCustomerOperationDetails(new GetCustomerOperationDetailsCommand {

                        OperationId = customerOperationId
                    });
         CustomerOperationDetailsVm vm = new CustomerOperationDetailsVm();

         vm.CustomerOperationDetails = result.Result;

        return PartialView("~/Views/Customer/OperationDetailsPartial.cshtml",vm);            
        }
```

Comment: i saw .html(data) should be html(result) but the result still fall error function. thanks

Comment: i couldn't find the error message in function (error).

Comment: Try to add endpoint to your controller to be able to detect the exception

Comment: I added but i couldn't find the error message sorry.

Comment: I updated my answer , i hope that this answer will help you now

Comment: i changed dataType: 'json' to dataType: 'html' and it worked.

Comment: You can chane it to html or remove it